# Can Ocelot (.NET) Transform One Incoming Request to Multiple API Requests

Tags: .net, microservices, api-gateway, ocelot

I'm designing a microservice architecture, and I'm considering using Ocelot as the API Gateway and RabbitMQ as the Message Queue.  My main application reads data and POSTs it to three microservices, each with different URLs and request bodies.  Instead of issuing three requests to the API Gateway for redirection, is it possible for me to send one large POST request to Ocelot, which would then split it into three separate APIs appropriately?

I've looked into Aggregation, but that doesn't seem to cover POST requests.

Comment: *I've looked into Aggregation, but that doesn't seem to cover POST requests.* - there's nothing in the documentation to suggest service aggregation doesn't work with POST... have you tried it?